# Cumulative Distribution Function in terms of the Error Function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, error-function

[image: Question]

[image: Question 2]

Hi, I have been asked to write the cumulative distribution function in terms of the error function for when x greater equal to zero.

I have made the substitution of t^2=z^2/2 to make them look similar but am unsure where to go from there.

Comment: Two hints: $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is an even function, and $\Phi(0)=1/2$. It would be helpful if you show your results.

Comment: @gammatester would the answer be $ Φ(x) = 1/2(1/ erf(2/sqrt(Pi)) $ ?

Comment: @J-Dorman what was the answer you eventually got?